# VBA code not working when complete codes are ran, but single line does work

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Cells(615, 1).Copy
Workbooks("PAIV005 - Draft Invoice Expenditure YTD").Worksheets("PPAIVTable").Cells(2, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("PAIV005 - Draft Invoice Expenditure YTD").Worksheets("PPAIVTable").Cells(3, 5).Copy
'PasteSpecial to paste values, formulas, formats, etc.
Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Cells(614, monthindex).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Activate
**If Application.IsNA(Cells(614, monthindex)) Then
Cells(614, monthindex).ClearContents
End If**
```

'I am trying to copy from one page to another although if that value is #N/A then it should clear the content otherwise the value.

Comment: What is not working? Also fully qualify your cells like you did for earlier lines instead of using `.Activate`. Fo exampe `If Application.IsNA(Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Cells(614, monthindex)) Then`. Do the same with `Cells(614, monthindex).ClearContents`. Change it to `Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Cells(614, monthindex).ClearContents` **Contd...**

Comment: It would be much better if you used objects so that you do not have to repeat big lines again and again. For example `Dim wb as workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx")`. Similarly `Dim ws as worksheet: Set ws= wb.Sheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel")`. You can then simply write `Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel").Cells(615, 1).Copy` as `ws.Cells(615, 1).Copy`.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. I am trying VBA for the first time & your codes really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Never repeat workbook or worksheet names like `Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel")`. Define a variable and set it to that worksheet and use that variable. In any case you need to change a name, you need only to change it in one place. Also code gets much more maintainable.
2. If one of your workbooks that you named is the workbook this code is written in then use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Workbooks("xxxxx.xlsx")`. `ThisWorkbook` refers always to the workbook the code is written in.
3. Make sure that all objects like `Range` or `Cells` that are located in a worksheet, are **always** fully specified. So **never** use something like `Cells(614, monthindex)` but **always** specify the worksheet these cells are in `wsCostOfTravel.Cells(614, monthindex)` if you don't Excel uses
   (epending on the scope the code is written in) the defined default workbook/worksheet for the scope. Since the defaults change with the scope you cannot tell what `Cells(x, y)` is refering to without knowing the scope of the code.
   That makes it kind of dangerous because if you copy that line of code because you want to do something similar eleswhere the code suddenly does something diffrent because the scope/default changed.

which worksheet you could have meant, and it might pick the wrong one!

So you would end up with something like:

```
Dim wsCostOfTravel As Worksheet
Set wsCostOfTravel = Workbooks("IT Denver YTD Apr'21.xlsx").Worksheets("Cost Inlusive of Travel")

Dim wsPPAIV As Worksheet
Set wsPPAIV = Workbooks("PAIV005 - Draft Invoice Expenditure YTD").Worksheets("PPAIVTable")

wsCostOfTravel.Cells(615, 1).Copy
wsPPAIV.Cells(2, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wsPPAIV.Cells(3, 5).Copy
'PasteSpecial to paste values, formulas, formats, etc.
wsCostOfTravel.Cells(614, monthindex).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

If Application.IsNA(wsCostOfTravel.Cells(614, monthindex)) Then
    wsCostOfTravel.Cells(614, monthindex).ClearContents
End If
```

And it is always faster to only transfer values instead of copying them. So you can replace your copy/paste lines with:

```
wsPPAIV.Cells(2, 5).Value = wsCostOfTravel.Cells(615, 1).Value
wsCostOfTravel.Cells(614, monthindex).Value = wsPPAIV.Cells(3, 5).Value
```

which only transfers the value. Note that the source and destination range in this case must be the same size. Which with only one cell is automatically the case.

Comment: Very good advice. I would add 4. If you only want to copy a value, write `wsDest.Cells(i,j).Value = wsOrig.Cells(i,j).Value` instead of using Excel's copy&paste.

Comment: Minor quibble: _if you don't Excel decides which worksheet you could have meant_ it would be clearer to be specific- `ActiveSheet` or `Me` depending on code scope

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, you are right. I didn't want to change the code too much so the OP could follow. But I added it to my answer. Thank's for your note!

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes, right there might be a few cases where you actually want to use `ActiveSheet` or especially with events `Me` becomes handy. In any case *never let Excel decide* which sheet you mean is a good idea. • I just try to avoid recommending something with `ActiveSheet` because then people start using `.Activate` wich isn't a good idea neither. Thanks for the worthy comment.

Comment: @peh yes, you and I know all that.  I just think _Excel decides_ leaves the door open for interpretation when the "Excel decision" is entirely predictable.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Well, true Excel does not really "decide" that's true. Probably better explained like: Depending on the scope the code is written in there are defaults for not specifying the worksheet and workbook. Since it changes with the scope you cannot tell what `Cells(x, y)` is refering to without knowing the scope of the code. That makes it kind of dangerous because if you copy that line of code because you want to do something similar eleswhere the code suddenly does something diffrent because the scope/default changed. (I changed my answer to be more precise.)

Comment: Thanks Chris & PEH for your support.